# Stuck at `sudo apt upgrade`, and can't get over `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. However, after trying to `sudo apt install ukui-desktop-environment` the installation was not successful. Sadly, doing `sudo apt upgrade` doesn't work either. I get the following message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ukui-control-center : Depends: kylin-nm (>= 3.1.1-2021+1029.1) but it is not installed
                       Depends: ukui-media (>= 3.0.0-64) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried many other options including the following various ones, individually.

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt remove --purge ukui-desktop-environment
sudo dpkg --configure --force-overwrite -a
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
```

Nothing works. I am pretty much stuck with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ukui-control-center : Depends: kylin-nm (>= 3.1.1-2021+1029.1) but it is not installed
                       Depends: ukui-media (>= 3.0.0-64) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Honestly, at this point, I no longer want the new package. I just want to be able to go back to how things were. How can I undo everything and just get back my original ubuntu?

Comment: Hi there @grateful, please try the FIRST answer on this page and let us know how you go https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: @Nmath `apt --fix-broken install` was one of the first things I tried... But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.

1. I deleted the ppas from the `Software & Updates > Other Software` app.
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt upgrade`
4. Followed by removing any remnants individually.
5. Ending it all by `sudo apt autoremove`.